# rename() not working in C under Win XP

Tags: c, rename

`rename("E348.def","E348__.hex");` works, but renaming does not work on files higher up on the directory tree.

Works- `rename("/tmp/test", "/tmp/test2");`

Doesn't work- `rename("/hex/E348.def","hex/E348__.hex" );`

Program path: `/hex/`.
The hex directory DOES exist and so do the files.
I'm running WIN XP.

Comment: Remember that `rename` returns a value indicating success/failure. When it indicates failure (it returns `-1`) then check [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) what went wrong. You can use [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string from the error. Print this error, and update the question to include it, and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: On Wndows, you should use backslashes \ instead of forward slashed `/`. Don't forget to double the backslashes `"\\"` in string constants.

Comment: Yeah, it returns -1 ....

Comment: @DidierTrosset Windows can handle forward slash in paths as well.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: I'v tried backslashes already and nothing.. still returns -1 ....

Comment: Is it an issue with file permissions? I.e does you current user have the rights to rename this file in the `/hex` directory.

Comment: Doesn't look like permissions, since the very first one works.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: I dont think so, because If I try to put files in current working directory (as I wrote rename("E348.def","E348__.hex");) I works... there is problem with the path I think but cant figure out what is causing the problem..... (also sorry, my english isnt perfect)

Comment: When `rename` fails, do e.g. `printf("rename failed, error #%d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));` and edit the question to include the printed text.

Comment: If you check the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/ there is said that "Its value shall follow the file name specifications of the running environment and can include a path (if supported by the system)." I think WIN XP should support this... or not?

Comment: @user3036674 Try this. ^^ `system("RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2");`

Comment: @KVD: I would like to use it, but my path is changing during the program so my path is char variable.. I dont know how to give system command path in this case.... if you know how to do it .. please help me...

Comment: This issue with using `/hex` directory, is that you're not anymore in the current directory. `/hex` is a directory at the root of your filesystem.

Comment: @Didier Trosset He is in Windows system, not *nix.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: Ok, this could be the problem, but I dont know how to get to hex from current directory... All I know is that the hex dir always be there... /dir where I will run my program/hex/ I'v already have variable where is saved the path to current working directory, but I dont know how to use it in rename().

Comment: Ok.. the problem was in slash on the  
beginning of path.. this is what it should like "hex/E348__.hex" :))) problem solved

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a move, not a rename:

```
rename("/hex/E348.def","hex/E348__.hex" );
        ^              ^
 leading slash        no slash
```

Answer (score 1):

`"/hex/E348.def"` is an absolute path. If your path is "...../here is my program/hex/", you should use `"hex/E348.def"`.